# How to generate custom xml and download it on button click in custom module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am creating a custom product feed module so I need to generate a Custom xml file which populate store products and also get download on button click.

Comment: Please share some code of your module.

Comment: You need how to create a custom xml file right?

Comment: yes @shivashankar I want to create custom xml file and download it on button click

Comment: You need download  button calling in xml file and click on it you need to get downloaded.